# How to highlight <p> not <div> in HTML using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have div's and p's in HTML and they both contain same text. I want to highlight the searched text from html paragraph only. How can I do that using jQuery ?

Like

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>
```

I want to highlight the 'world' in the paragraph tag.

Comment: but there is also hello in `<p>` tag, don't u want to highlight that one??

Comment: `var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("p");  for (var index=0; index<nodes.length; index++) {  var node = nodes[index];  if (node.innerHTML.indexOf(searchTerm) != -1) {  node.style.backgroundColor = "green";  }  }`

Comment: @aroth: 1) Why would you post code in a comment? 2) Why use framework-less js when it's tagged as jQuery?

Comment: @Demian Brecht - #2 is the answer to #1; the OP asked for an answer using jQuery, and I was providing non-jQuery code, so it's not really appropriate as an answer.  As for #2, I think jQuery is overused for solving simple problems like this one, and wanted to point out that a trivial non-framework solution exists.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a class to the entire `p` element.

```
$('p:contains("Hello")').addClass('highlight');
```

Otherwise, you'll need to [iterate over the text nodes and then wrap the match with a `span`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444409/in-javascript-how-can-i-replace-text-in-an-html-page-without-affecting-the-tags).

Comment: Ugh.. Damn AFK'ing in the midst of fiddling : / (6 minutes later..) +1 for being more focused than I ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

```
var str = "World";

$('p:contains('+str+')').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xpums/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').each(function(index) { // Find every paragraph and run through them
    if($(this).text() === "world") { // Check if current paragraph's text is "world"
        $(this).addClass("itemFound"); // Apply styling
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do case insensitive search and add a highlight class.

```
var str = /world/gi;
jQuery("p").each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).text().match(str) {
        jQuery(this).addClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this inside the body

```
<script>

    $("body").find("p").eq(1).css("background-color","green");
</script>
```