# Javascript replace undefined error ends but not replace continues

Tags: javascript, html, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript replace undefined error shows!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410862/javascript-replace-undefined-error-shows)

Friends i got success with this piece of code:

```
var avidno = '800.123.1234';
var bodytext = document.body.innerHTML;
var newbodytext;
function validate () {
var regex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;

if (regex.test(avidno)) {
    alert('bingo');
    var avidno_new = '<span>'+avidno+'</span>';
    var newbodytext = bodytext.replace(new RegExp(avidno, "g"), avidno_new);
    document.body.innerHTML = newbodytext;
    // Valid international phone number
} else {
    alert('uupss');
    // Invalid international phone number
}
}
validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (not sure about cross-browser):

```
newaltr = bodytext.replace(avidno, altrstr, "g");
```

Comment: its works :) in firefox, but chrome, ie etc etc not working

Answer (score 0):

Your regex includes ^ and $, which force the regex to match only the whole string. That's probably the reason why replace fails.

Try this (untested):

```
var avidno = '(800)123 1234';
var bodytext = document.body.innerHTML;
var newaltr;

function validate () {
    var format = '\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})';
    var bodytext, altrstr, newtext;

    if (RegExp('^' + format + '$').test(avidno)) {
        // This could be done in a single line, but this way it's clearer
        bodytext = document.body.innerHTML;
        altrstr = '<span>'+avidno+'</span>';
        newtext = bodytext.replace(RegExp(format, 'g'), altrstr);
        document.body.innerHTML = newtext;

        // Valid international phone number
    } else {
        alert('uupss');
        // Invalid international phone number
    }
}
validate();
```