# Replace a phrase in a HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to replace a phrase in a HTML document with another phrase? I'm not sure if this is possible with JavaScript but here would be an example:

```
String thePhrase = "this is the phrase to replace";
String toReplace = "this is the phrase that replaces thePhrase";
replace(thePhrase, toReplace);
```

Something like this would then search through the HTML document and replace thePhrase with toReplace.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Have you looked anything up?

Comment: You need to replase all text in the document from X to Y?

Comment: Replace the data at it's source, not onLoad client side. That or do this in PHP.

Comment: @dystroy is because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140844/replacing-a-line-of-code-in-html

Comment: @dystroy because the most feasible way to do this is server side.

Comment: We really need to know more. For example : is the sentence in one element or may it cover more ?

Comment: @dystroy It's if I were to replace "<link href="<link here>.php" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >" within a document.

Comment: @user3040555 you don't replace elements by searching text, you search the node itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, how can I replace text in an HTML page without affecting the tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444409/in-javascript-how-can-i-replace-text-in-an-html-page-without-affecting-the-tags)

Comment: You have no idea what you are doing. Please learn on your own and ask for help when you need it, we are not a code writing service.

Comment: Use querySelectorAll to get your `link` elements and do the replacement on those element's innerText/textContent

Comment: @user3040555 Please edit your question. Do not add details in the comments. READ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Jhawins I don't want to learn the language. I'm with a website builder site and this is the only thing I need to do. And I am not wanting to learn the fundamentals of a language if I want to do something like this. Anyway, I'm not liking the community here so I'll be better off asking my web host.

Comment: @user3040555 What I did was only trying to help you get the best answer. The OS is great. Helped me a lot, but for you to be helped, you have to help people understand their problem and this should be done in the matter and not in the comments.

Comment: @user3040555 yes, please never use this site if you don't want to learn anything.

Comment: @user3040555 we don't really care if you don't like us :). But good luck.

Comment: @user3040555 This is not a problem you will have with the stackoverflow community, but anywhere in the world you do not inform the resources used and make clear what you really need, you will not get a satisfactory answer. Forgive us if we are not magicians or fortunetellers. :) What I did was just to help you.

Comment: I appreciate your help @GuilhermeNascimento. I'm use to a Java forum I use and I only have a brief knowledge of how to use HTML. It's really tough trying to understand a new language and forum just like that. That's why I thought it'd be easiest to describe what I need with Java. But anyway, I've asked the web host what to do and hopefully they give me a decent reply. It really only would take someone with knowledge a few minutes to help.

Comment: @user3040555 Maybe they (http://www.enjin.com/) can help you because they know the system and modules (HTML module). But here nobody knew what the tool and the module you were using, you can not blame them (stackoverflow users) because they did not have the exact basis of his doubts to understand what you really need. Anyway good luck.

Comment: @user3040555 `Java !== javascript`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here you have an example of how you can do it using p tags and jQuery. Hope it helps

```
var thePhrase = "this is the phrase to replace";
var toReplace = "this is the phrase that replaces thePhrase";
$("p").each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.html() == thePhrase) {
        $this.html( toReplace );
    }
});
```

See a demo of it here http://jsfiddle.net/sousatg/w3jCj/

Comment: Let's say you have an anchor `<a>` tag inside your `<p>` tag with an event listener attached to it. This script would break that event listner because the original `<a>` tag would be lost along with all events bound to it, because you're replacing them with new tags.

Comment: As you can see by this example http://jsfiddle.net/sousatg/w3jCj/5/ it does not break.

Comment: Oh, I misread your code. I thought you were actually doing a find and replace. Your code just replaces the content if the inner html exactly matches the search string, so nevermind, my mistake :)

Comment: This probably got downvoted because jQuery shouldn't be involved and `.text()` should be used rather than `.html()`. In vanilla JS, that would be `elem.textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to recursively go through every node on the page, starting with `document.body` and whenever you hit a text node, replace the text there.

```
var findAndReplaceAllText = function(node, needle, replacement){
    if(node.nodeName == 'SCRIPT') return; /* don't mess with script tags */
    if(node.nodeType == 3) /* if node type is text, replace text */
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(needle, replacement);
    for(var i = node.childNodes.length; i--;) /* loop through all child nodes */
        findAndReplaceAllText(node.childNodes[i], needle, replacement);
};
findAndReplaceAllText(document.body, /this/g, 'anything but that');
```

If you modify the html directly using `innerHTML` or jQuery's `.html()` method, then it has a high potential to break other scripts on the page that reference those elements, like event handlers. So, this is a better way.

Regardless, if you need to do this, then it's highly likely that you're approaching a problem in an improper way and should try to find a better way to accomplish your goal.